# How Do I save the user's image fetched from fbprofilepictureview using the Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

So I'm implementing the Facebook login button in an iOS app I'm currently working on, I'm trying to save the user's profile picture that's accessed using this line;

```
self.profilePicture.profileID = user.id;
```

I haven't had any luck storing that image for use elsewhere in the app. I have tried a number of methods including this approach

```
imageUrl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?redirect=true", user.username];
```

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `user.objectID` and not `user.username`.

You can also use my drop-in replacement for FBProfilePictureView, [DBFBProfilePictureView](https://github.com/combinatorial/DBFBProfilePictureView). This exposes the imageView as a readonly property. Using that, your code would be something like this...

```
self.profilePicture.completionHandler = ^(DBFBProfilePictureView* view, NSError* error){
    if(error) {
        view.showEmptyImage = YES;
        NSLog(@"Loading profile picture failed with error: %@", error);
    } else {
        UIImage *image = view.imageView.image;
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [imageData writeToFile:filename atomically:NO];
    }
};
```

Comment: user.profileID doesn't exist.
EDIT: It does exist but it's user.objectID. Thanks!!!

Comment: If you could edit your answer to reflect that, I'll be happy to accept and give you your well deserved points :)